Understand Look Up Tables
I am trying to understand how the Address Look Up Tables work under the hood.
I understand that you can include multiple transactions, cause address are kinda referenced by a 1 byte 'pointer' or something similar. The thing I don't understand is how.
And also I don't understand if a look up Table is extended let's say with an array x which contains 22 keypairs. Why in the case when I send a transaction of transferring solana to other 22 keypairs, and I add that transaction in the lookup table, I get an error.
My assumption, is a lookup table references 22 addresses by 1 byte.
I assume there is a starting point or transaction, and the next ones have an offset that is between 0-255, otherwise I can't understand how this could be implemented and works under the hood.

Here is the documentation for Solana Address Lookup Tables (LUT)
https://solana.com/docs/advanced/lookup-tables
The TLDR is this;

Create a LUT
Add addresses
Use LUT

Advantages = Can add 256 addresses per table AND the LUT can be reused

To answer your question better, please provide more information such as the error you are facing or the task you are trying to achieve.

I do not understand what is the point of extending the table? @Metasal

Extend means to add more.
The full description is here https://docs.rs/solana-sdk/1.18.18/solana_sdk/address_lookup_table/instruction/enum.ProgramInstruction.html#variant.ExtendLookupTable
